# Bioinformatics career outlook and education requirement?

Tags: job, education, biology, bioinformatics

I'm currently applying to a graduate school PhD program and have a question regarding bioinformatics field.

Can a person with Biology PhD degree who works in a lab that is heavily informatics, biostats, and genetics focus have a negative chance when applying to industry positions such as tech (heard a lot of news that Google and AWS are jumping into bioinformatics)?

I have experience in programming (Python and R) and working at bioinformatics labs but worried that having a Biology PhD degree would screen me out.

I know some people may have some questions why biology Ph.D. when I have an interest in bioinformatics, the schools I applied to keep redirecting my application to biology when I applied for bioinformatics.

Comment: Sorry, the post is off-topic as we do not give career advice outside academia here, but yes, it is possible. The name of the degree does not matter. What you did and your experience matter.

Answer (score 2):

The degree title shouldn't really matter at this level. PhDs are much more bespoke than undergraduate programs, so anyone recruiting PhD holders should know to look beyond the degree title into the particular experience and skills. So just be sure to communicate those aspects (which you should be doing anyway!) and you should be fine.

Anecdotally, I don't believe our institution even offers 'Bioinformatics PhD' programs despite having a number of active groups in that area, with everyone being awarded PhDs under biology or medicine, as appropriate.